# Issue with safari and :after ,:before { box-sizing:border-box; }

Tags: html, css, safari

I am having trouble with safari not box-sizing correct .after "load".
 Works great for chrome firefox and IE but not safari.

Here is the page in question: goo.gl/HKJy4g

I am talking about the 3 div's "feat1,feat2,feat3 that is on the right-hand side of web design content in the header. I am not sure what I am doing wrong for it not to work in safari.

Not sure if I did a good job explaining, not really good at typing out my thoughts =(

Comment: You should post a working code snippet reproducing the issue **within the question**, not as an external link. Also, _not box-sizing correct_ is not very descriptive, a drawing of the expected output would most likely help.

Comment: Alright, what I am trying to do is make the three images (which are div boxes using backgrounds) responsive and fit in the header area no matter what. Not sure how to replicate this in a code snippet, but it works on all browsers but safari. So by using box-sizing it reset the element .after to make sure it fits.

Comment: you know what I think I found my answer http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing  I think it is because I am using display: table ... can anyone confirm?

Comment: Nope, it is not possible to generally confirm something like that

Answer (score 0):

I just sow your website, the problem is with `.feat3` element
the `left: 500px;` is pushing the div out of context and make `.overlay` div overflows.